# AttributeError while loading textHero library

Tags: python, text, nlp

I am getting an error when importing textHero

```
#import the texthero library
import texthero as hero
import pandas as pd
```

Error : AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'data'

I have installed textHero again but error did not get resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the gensim version to 3.8. worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post the whole error message?

Anyway, you should be able to solve the problem by uninstalling and installing again [NLTK](http://nltk.org/):

```
pip uninstall nltk
pip install -U nltk
```

Answer (score 0):

After importing the "texthero" library. It showed an error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.sklearn_api'

I have tried to install 'gensim.sklearn_api', but no such module available yet.

Also, created the new anaconda environment for an older version of python-like 3.6 and 3.7 but It showed the same error message.

I have installed the older version of texthero and its work

> pip install texthero==1.0.5

The older version of texthero==1.0.5 is very much compatible with python version like 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8
[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]